# Stata 13: Encoding of German Characters in Windows 8 and Mac OS X

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, stata

For a current project, I use a number of csv files that are saved in UTF8. The motivation for this encoding is that it contains information in German with special characters ä,ö,ü,ß. My team is working with Stata 13 on Mac OS X and Windows 7 (software is frequently updated).

When we import the csv file (when importing, we choose Latin-1) in Stata special characters are correctly displayed on both operating system. However, when we export the dataset to another csv file on Mac OS X - which we need to do quite often in our setup - the special characters are replaced, e.g. ä -> Š, ü -> Ÿ etc. On Windows, exporting works like a charme and special characters are not replaced.

**Troubleshooting**: Stata 13 cannot interpret unicode. I have tried to convert the utf8 files to windows1252 and latin 1 (iso 8859-1) encoding (since, after all, all it contains are german characters) using Sublime Text 2 prior to importing it in Stata. However the same problem remains for Mac OS X.

Yesterday, Stata 14 was announced which apparently can deal with unicode. If that is the reason, then it would probably help with my problem, however, we will not be able to upgrade soon. Apart from then, I am wondering why the problem arises on Mac but not on Windows? Can anyone help? Thank you.

**[EDIT Start]** When I import the exported csv file again using a "Mac Roman" Text encoding (Stata allows to specify that in the importing dialogue), then my german special characters appear again. Apparently I am not the only one encountering this problem by the looks of [this thread](https://github.com/statatmbundle/Stata.tmbundle/issues/5). However, because I need to work with the exported csv files, I still need a solution to this problem. **[EDIT End]**

**[EDIT2 Start]** One example is the word "Bösdorf" that is changed to "Bšsdorf". In the original file the hex code is 42c3 b673 646f 7266, whereas the hex code in the exported file is 42c5 a173 646f 7266. **[EDIT2 End]**

Comment: How are the incorrectly exported characters represented? Do you get a literal Unicode [CAPITAL S WITH CARON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/160/index.htm) or a regular S with a combining caron (which is the normal form on the Mac)?  See also [CAPITAL Y WITH TREMA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0178/index.htm) and maybe (ahem) https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: how can I find out for sure? The characters on the linked pages do look exactly like what is generated from Stata though, yes. Please keep in mind that Stata imports the csv as latin 1 (though original source encoding is utf8). I presume that the output is latin 1 as well. Are there any problems with latin 1 on macs?

Comment: The actual bytes in the file will be different.  A hex dump of a short sample would be instructive.  See also the [character-encoding tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some hints.

Comment: So I again edited my post in order to include the hex code of an example where the problem appears. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the bug gets fixed, you can work around this with

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252 <oldfile.csv | iconv -f mac -t utf-8 >newfile.csv
```

This undoes an incorrect transcoding which apparently the export function in Stata performs internally.

Based on your indicators, `cp1252` seems like a good guess, but it could also be `cp1254`.  More examples could help settle the issue if you can't figure it out (common German characters to test with still would include ä and the uppercase umlauts, the German double s ligature ß, etc).

Comment: What is an “uppercase umlaut”?  Apart from U+0345 `COMBINING GREEK YPOGEGRAMMENI` alone, combining characters do not have case. Certainly U+0308  `COMBINING DIAERESIS` does not, nor does U+00A8       `DIAERESIS`.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, I mean the uppercase versions of Ü, Ä, and Ö.

Comment: Oh, you mean U+00C4  `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS` and such.   Unicode 6.0 has 34 code points that are considered uppercase and whose decomposed form contains U+0308 `COMBINING DIAERESIS`.

Comment: Yeah, but only those three are likely to occur naturally in German text, especially if the original source is in some legacy 8-bit encoding.

Comment: @triplee converting from mac to utf-8 worked out. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Stata 13 and below uses a deprecated locale in Mac OS X, macroman (Mac OS X is unicode). I generally used StatTransfer to convert, for example, from Excel (unicode) to Stata (Western, macroman; Options->Encoding options) in Spanish language. It was the only way to have á, é, etc. Furthermore, Stata 14 imports unicode without problem but insist to export es_ES (Spanish Spain) as the default locale, having to add the command locale UTF-8 at the end of the export command to have a readable Excel file.